# matlab reshape function - error on number of elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Hi  I have the following code

```
 A = squeeze(hourly_surplus(1,1,1,:));
    B = reshape(A,365,24);
```

Where size(A) = 8760 x 1

however I get the error

```
 Error using reshape
 To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change
```

This error appears on the line of "B", however I think that A has 8760 elements and B = 365 x 24 which also is 8760. What could be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: check size(A), is it really [8760,1]?

Comment: Does `size(A)` actually return 8760 x 1?

Comment: Yes ! - This is what I really don't understand!   
                                                                    >> size(A)

ans =

        8760           1

Comment: @user643469 I mean the values in the matrix, are they double? what type are they?

Comment: @user643469 Use `class(A)` to find out the "type" of A.

Comment: can i not reshape it if it is class "double" ??

Comment: @user643469 I don't see how that's possible, if A is a 8760x1 matrix of doubles it is the same as the random A in my answer, so it should work. Does the code from my example work?

Comment: yes your example works. also there are no NaN values (just in case that could make a difference)

Comment: This sounds really weird... One more thing: Does `numel(A)` return 8760?

Comment: is there a way to debug then?

Comment: How about `reshape(A, 1, [])` or `reshape(A, 365, [])`? Do any of these work?

Comment: In the workspace window, do you see: A   <8760x1 double> ?

Comment: @ 3lectrologos - I can do the reshape(A,1,[]), but not the reshape(A,365,[]) as it gives the same error

Comment: @ bitwise - when  I run class(A) all I get is double - not <8760x1 double>

Comment: @user643469 Yes, that was expected. What is `size(B)` after `B = reshape(A, 1, [])`? Also, how about `B = reshape(reshape(A, 1, []), 365, [])`?

Comment: @user643469 You can open a workspace window (use the menu) and see all your variables, their sizes and their types - do you see there <8760x1 double>?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
A=rand(8760,1);
B=reshape(A,365,24);
```

works fine, so the problem is with your A.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the size function I ran at the command window on "A" in my comment above. it definitely is 8760 x 1